# My turtle object on the screen is not appearing

Tags: python, python-turtle

First, I import the `turtle` module and then creating a screen. After that, I try to create a turtle object, but it is not showed on the screen. Could anyone tell me what the issue is? I have written the following code in PyCharm:

```
import turtle as t

screen = t.Screen()
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.exitonclick()


terry = t.Turtle(shape='square')
terry.color('white')
terry.goto(0, 0)
```

Comment: Could you try to move the turtle code between the `screen.bgcolor()` and the `screen.exitonclick()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `screen.exitonclick()` method does not only set the property that the screen will close after clicking it, it does also wait for this to happen. As this method waits for the screen to close, every code that is after it won't be executed untill the user closes the screen by clicking on it.

This means that the turtle will be created after the screen is closed and thus does not show up as the screen is closed. The solution for this is moving the `screen.exitonclick()` line to the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

screen.exitonclick() seems to wait for a mouse click before continuing. As you define your turtle after that, it doesn't come up on the screen. Try putting screen.exitonclick() at the very end of the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have the `screen.exitonclick()` in the middle. That generates another window that apears and desapears after `screen.exitonclick()` is executed. What you should do is to put `screen.exitonclick()` at the end.

```
import turtle as t

screen = t.Screen()
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")



terry = t.Turtle(shape='square')
terry.color('white')
terry.goto(0, 0)
screen.exitonclick()
```

This would be the code.

Answer (score 0):

`exitonclick()` is not the best way to keep the program open. It is better to use `done()` or `mainloop()`.

They do the exact same job but they are more user friendly. Software normally requires you to click the X button because it is more friendly. Imagine playing your game or using software and it closes when you click it.

My alternatives are superior since they are consistent, controlling, compatible and like mentioned, better for everyone and for actual software.

Here is the new code with the problem fixed and better alternative added:

```
import turtle as t

screen = t.Screen()
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")

terry = t.Turtle(shape='square')
terry.color('white')
terry.goto(0, 0)
t.done()
```